# Problema com Dicionários em Python

Tags: python

```py
def main():
    insereDic()
def insereDic():
    frase = input('>>>')
    for i in frase:
        if i in dic:
            dic[i] =+ 1
        else:
            dic[i] = 1
    print(dic)
dic = {}
main()
```

Enunciado do Exercício

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDShb.png

O resultado no terminal com o input "algoritmos e programacao" é: {'a': 1, 'l': 1, 'g': 1, 'o': 1, 'r': 1, 'i': 1, 't': 1, 'm': 1, 's': 1, ' ': 1, 'e': 1, 'p': 1, 'c': 1}

Ao invés de: {'a': 4, 'l': 1, 'g': 2, 'o': 4, 'r': 3, 'i': 1, 't': 1, 'm': 2, 's': 1, ' ': 2, 'e': 1, 'p': 1, 'c': 1} (que seria o correto do exercício)

Answer (score 1):

Bryan, o problema está apenas no momento de incrementa o valor da chave já existente, o correto é **+=**:

```
def main():
    insereDic()

def insereDic():
    frase = input('>>>')

    for i in frase:
        if i in dic:
            dic[i] += 1
        else:
            dic[i] = 1
    print(dic)

dic = {}
main()
```